# Detect tap in page?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a `PhoneApplicationPage` with some grids, images and a few buttons. If I tap outside my buttons, anywhere in the page (on an image, grid or whatever), I want to open a new page.

How can I detect a tap/click anywhere on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two ways to do that:

1. Listen to the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event on your `PhoneApplicationPage`. It should be triggered by images and labels but not by buttons
2. Listen to the `Tap` event on your `PhoneApplicationPage`. However, this event will be triggered even when the user tap on a button. To prevent this, you can retrieve the list of controls at the tap coordinates in the event handler, and open the new page only if there's no button:

   ```
   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
   {
       var element = (UIElement)sender;

       var controls = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(element), element);

       if(controls.OfType<Button>().Any())
       {
           return;
       }

       // Open the new page
   }
   ```

Comment: I suppose checking the type of `e.OriginalSource` would be the same?

Comment: Unfortunately no. A control like `Button` is composed of many child controls, and the original source will be the child control. So instead of finding `Button` in `e.OriginalSource`, you'll find for instance `Border`.